# Getting a 4.0 GPA

Tags: python, python-2.x

This is my code, for calculating a GPA for 7 subjects. It works, but is there a better way? Any hints on making it more flexible?

```
from __future__ import division

import string



print "This program will calculate a Semester GPA for a given set of courses. Enter 0 in all inputs, if you want to skip extra courses.\n"

cname1 = raw_input("First course name: ")


while True:
    cred1 = raw_input("First course credit: ")
    try:
        i = int(cred1)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print 'Invalid input, Should be an positive interger'

grade1 = raw_input("First course grade: ")

choice1 = grade1

while choice1 not in ["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]:

    print 'Invalid choice'

    grade1 = raw_input("First course grade: ")

    users_turn = choice1 in ["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]

    choice1 = grade1

cname2 = raw_input("Second course name: ")

while True:
    cred2 = raw_input("Second course credit: ")
    try:
        i = int(cred2)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print 'Invalid input, Should be an positive interger'

grade2 = raw_input("Second course grade: ")

choice2 = grade2

while choice2 not in ["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]:

    print 'Invalid choice'

    grade2 = raw_input("Second course grade: ")

    users_turn = choice2 in ["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]

    choice2 = grade2

cname3 = raw_input("Third course name: ")


while True:
    cred3 = raw_input("Third course credit: ")
    try:
        i = int(cred3)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print 'Invalid input, Should be an positive interger'

grade3 = raw_input("Third course grade: ")

choice3 = grade3

while choice3 not in ["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]:

    print 'Invalid choice'

    grade3 = raw_input("Third course grade: ")

    users_turn = choice3 in ["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]

    choice3 = grade3


cname4 = raw_input("Fourth course name: ")

while True:
    cred4 = raw_input("Fourth course credit: ")
    try:
        i = int(cred4)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print 'Invalid input, Should be an positive interger'

grade4 = raw_input("Fourth course grade: ")

choice4 = grade4

while choice4 not in ["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]:

    print 'Invalid choice'

    grade4 = raw_input("Fourth course grade: ")

    users_turn = choice4 in ["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]

    choice4 = grade4

cname5 = raw_input("Fifth course name: ")

while True:
    cred5 = raw_input("Fifth course credit: ")
    try:
        i = int(cred5)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print 'Invalid input, Should be an positive interger'

grade5 = raw_input("Fifth course grade: ")

choice5 = grade5

while choice5 not in ["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]:

    print 'Invalid choice'

    grade5 = raw_input("Fifth course grade: ")

    users_turn = choice5 in ["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]

    choice5 = grade5

cname6 = raw_input("Sixth course name: ")

while True:
    cred6 = raw_input("Sixth course credit: ")
    try:
        i = int(cred6)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print 'Invalid input, Should be an positive interger'

grade6 = raw_input("Sixth course grade: ")

choice6 = grade6

while choice6 not in ["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]:

    print 'Invalid choice'

    grade6 = raw_input("Sixth course grade: ")

    users_turn = choice6 in ["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]

    choice6 = grade6

cname7 = raw_input("Seventh course name: ")

while True:
    cred7 = raw_input("Seventh course credit: ")
    try:
        i = int(cred7)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print 'Invalid input, Should be an positive interger'

grade7 = raw_input("Seventh course grade: ")

choice7 = grade7

while choice7 not in ["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]:

    print 'Invalid choice'

    grade7 = raw_input("Seventh course grade: ")

    users_turn = choice7 in ["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]

    choice7 = grade7






totalGPA = 0.0

overallGPA = 0.0


cred1i = string.atoi(cred1)

cred2i = string.atoi(cred2)

cred3i = string.atoi(cred3)

cred4i = string.atoi(cred4)

cred5i = string.atoi(cred5)

cred6i = string.atoi(cred6)

cred7i = string.atoi(cred7)

if grade1 in {"A+", "a+", "A", "a"}:

    c1points = (4.0*cred1i)

elif grade1 in {"A-", "a-"}:

    c1points = (3.67*cred1i)

elif grade1 in {"B+", "b+"}: 

    c1points = (3.33*cred1i)

elif grade1 in {"B", "b"}:

    c1points = (3.0*cred1i)

elif grade1 in {"B-", "b-"}:

    c1points = (2.67*cred1i)

elif grade1 in {"C+", "c+"}:

    c1points = (2.33*cred1i)

elif grade1 in {"C", "c"}:

    c1points = (2.0*cred1i)

elif grade1 in {"C-", "c-"}:

    c1points = (1.67*cred1i)

elif grade1 in {"D+", "d+"}:

    c1points = (1.33*cred1i)

elif grade1 in {"D", "d"}:

    c1points = (1.0*cred1i)

else:

    c1points = 0.0



if grade2 in {"A+", "a+", "A", "a"}:

    c2points = (4.0*cred2i)

elif grade2 in {"A-", "a-"}:

    c2points = (3.67*cred2i)

elif grade2 in {"B+", "b+"}: 

    c2points = (3.33*cred2i)

elif grade2 in {"B", "b"}:

    c2points = (3.0*cred2i)

elif grade2 in {"B-", "b-"}:

    c2points = (2.67*cred2i)

elif grade2 in {"C+", "c+"}:

    c2points = (2.33*cred2i)

elif grade2 in {"C", "c"}:

    c2points = (2.0*cred2i)

elif grade2 in {"C-", "c-"}:

    c2points = (1.67*cred2i)

elif grade2 in {"D+", "d+"}:

    c2points = (1.33*cred2i)

elif grade2 in {"D", "d"}:

    c2points = (1.0*cred2i)

else:

    c2points = 0.0


if grade3 in {"A+", "a+", "A", "a"}:

    c3points = (4.0*cred3i)

elif grade3 in {"A-", "a-"}:

    c3points = (3.67*cred3i)

elif grade3 in {"B+", "b+"}: 

    c3points = (3.33*cred3i)

elif grade3 in {"B", "b"}:

    c3points = (3.0*cred3i)

elif grade3 in {"B-", "b-"}:

    c3points = (2.67*cred3i)

elif grade3 in {"C+", "c+"}:

    c3points = (2.33*cred3i)

elif grade3 in {"C", "c"}:

    c3points = (2.0*cred3i)

elif grade3 in {"C-", "c-"}:

    c3points = (1.67*cred3i)

elif grade3 in {"D+", "d+"}:

    c3points = (1.33*cred3i)

elif grade3 in {"D", "d"}:

    c3points = (1.0*cred3i)

else:

    c3points = 0.0


if grade4 in {"A+", "a+", "A", "a"}:

    c4points = (4.0*cred4i)

elif grade4 in {"A-", "a-"}:

    c4points = (3.67*cred4i)

elif grade4 in {"B+", "b+"}: 

    c4points = (3.33*cred4i)

elif grade4 in {"B", "b"}:

    c4points = (3.0*cred4i)

elif grade4 in {"B-", "b-"}:

    c1points = (2.67*cred4i)

elif grade4 in {"C+", "c+"}:

    c4points = (2.33*cred4i)

elif grade4 in {"C", "c"}:

    c4points = (2.0*cred4i)

elif grade4 in {"C-", "c-"}:

    c1points = (1.67*cred4i)

elif grade4 in {"D+", "d+"}:

    c4points = (1.33*cred4i)

elif grade4 in {"D", "d"}:

    c4points = (1.0*cred4i)

else:

    c4points = 0.0


if grade5 in {"A+", "a+", "A", "a"}:

    c5points = (4.0*cred5i)

elif grade5 in {"A-", "a-"}:

    c5points = (3.67*cred5i)

elif grade5 in {"B+", "b+"}: 

    c5points = (3.33*cred5i)

elif grade5 in {"B", "b"}:

    c5points = (3.0*cred5i)

elif grade5 in {"B-", "b-"}:

    c5points = (2.67*cred5i)

elif grade5 in {"C+", "c+"}:

    c5points = (2.33*cred5i)

elif grade5 in {"C", "c"}:

    c5points = (2.0*cred5i)

elif grade5 in {"C-", "c-"}:

    c5points = (1.67*cred5i)

elif grade5 in {"D+", "d+"}:

    c5points = (1.33*cred5i)

elif grade5 in {"D", "d"}:

    c5points = (1.0*cred5i)

else:

    c5points = 0.0

if grade6 in {"A+", "a+", "A", "a"}:

    c6points = (4.0*cred6i)

elif grade6 in {"A-", "a-"}:

    c6points = (3.67*cred6i)

elif grade6 in {"B+", "b+"}: 

    c6points = (3.33*cred6i)

elif grade6 in {"B", "b"}:

    c6points = (3.0*cred6i)

elif grade6 in {"B-", "b-"}:

    c6points = (2.67*cred6i)

elif grade6 in {"C+", "c+"}:

    c6points = (2.33*cred6i)

elif grade6 in {"C", "c"}:

    c6points = (2.0*cred6i)

elif grade6 in {"C-", "c-"}:

    c6points = (1.67*cred6i)

elif grade6 in {"D+", "d+"}:

    c6points = (1.33*cred6i)

elif grade6 in {"D", "d"}:

    c6points = (1.0*cred6i)

else:

    c6points = 0.0


if grade7 in {"A+", "a+", "A", "a"}:

    c7points = (4.0*cred7i)

elif grade7 in {"A-", "a-"}:

    c7points = (3.67*cred7i)

elif grade7 in {"B+", "b+"}: 

    c7points = (3.33*cred7i)

elif grade7 in {"B", "b"}:

    c7points = (3.0*cred7i)

elif grade7 in {"B-", "b-"}:

    c7points = (2.67*cred7i)

elif grade1 in {"C+", "c+"}:

    c7points = (2.33*cred7i)

elif grade7 in {"C", "c"}:

    c7points = (2.0*cred7i)

elif grade7 in {"C-", "c-"}:

    c7points = (1.67*cred7i)

elif grade7 in {"D+", "d+"}:

    c7points = (1.33*cred7i)

elif grade7 in {"D", "d"}:

    c7points = (1.0*cred7i)

else:

    c7points = 0.0



totalCredits = cred1i+cred2i+cred3i+cred4i+cred5i+cred6i+cred7i

overallGPA = (c1points + c2points + c3points + c4points + c5points + c7points + c7points)/totalCredits

cname1 = cname1.ljust(15)

cred1 = cred1.center(9)

grade1 = grade1.center(6)

cname2 = cname2.ljust(15)

cred2 = cred2.center(9)

grade2 = grade2.center(6)

cname3 = cname3.ljust(15)

cred3 = cred3.center(9)

grade3 = grade3.center(6)

cname4 = cname4.ljust(15)

cred4 = cred4.center(9)

grade4 = grade4.center(6)

cname5 = cname5.ljust(15)

cred5 = cred5.center(9)

grade5 = grade5.center(6)

cname6 = cname6.ljust(15)

cred6 = cred6.center(9)

grade6 = grade6.center(6)

cname7 = cname7.ljust(15)

cred7 = cred1.center(9)

grade7 = grade7.center(6)




print "COURSE         CREDITS  GRADE \n"

print "------         -------  ----- \n"

print '%s%s%s' % (cname1, cred1, grade1)

print '%s%s%s' % (cname2, cred2, grade2)

print '%s%s%s' % (cname3, cred3, grade3)

print '%s%s%s' % (cname4, cred4, grade4)

print '%s%s%s' % (cname5, cred5, grade5)

print '%s%s%s' % (cname6, cred6, grade6)

print '%s%s%s' % (cname7, cred7, grade7)

print "SEMESTER GPA = %.2f" % (overallGPA)
```

Comment: Just to clarify: does your code work?

Comment: Are you new to Python or programming in general? If so, add the [tag:beginner] tag to your question.

Answer (score 8):

You've a long way to go here. Much of your code is repetitive, which (in case you have a mistake in your logic, for example) will give you maintenance headaches. Until your code is de-cluttered by refactoring (i.e. replacing it with simpler code having equivalent functionality - by analogy with refactoring algebraic expressions to make them simpler to understand) it's difficult to make other suggestions for improving it.

For example, you repeat the string `["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]` umpteen times. If you assigned this to a global variable called `valid_marks` your code will read more lucidly, but more importantly if the set of valid marks were ever to change you could make the change in exactly one place rather than having to go through the code, possibly missing some occurrences.

The blank lines in your code do not enhance readability.

You have many sections of logic which are essentially the same in all but details. You should really generalize these. For example, you write

```
cname4 = raw_input("Fourth course name: ")
while True:
    cred4 = raw_input("Fourth course credit: ")
    try:
        i = int(cred4)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print 'Invalid input, Should be an positive interger'

grade4 = raw_input("Fourth course grade: ")
choice4 = grade4
while choice4 not in ["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]:
    print 'Invalid choice'
    grade4 = raw_input("Fourth course grade: ")
    users_turn = choice4 in ["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]
    choice4 = grade4
```

This code essentially reads the credit and the grade for a specific conference, and could easily be encapsulated into a function such as

```
def get_credit_and_score(course_name):
    cname = raw_input(course_name+" name: ")
    while True:
        cred = raw_input(course_name" credit: ")
        try:
            i = int(cred)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print 'Invalid input, Should be an positive integer'

    grade = raw_input(course_name+" grade: ")
    while grade not in valid_marks:
        print 'Invalid choice'
        grade = raw_input(course_name+" grade: ")
    return cred, choice
```

I have removed the `choiceN` and `users_turn` variables because I couldn't really see what use they served. This might have been an error, do feel free to correct me.

This allows you to simplify your login considerably by writing

```
cred1, choice1 = get_credit_and_score("First course")
cred2, choice2 = get_credit_and_score("Second course")
    ...
cred7, choice7 = get_credit_and_score("Seventh course")
```

Once you had made those changes you could consider building a list of inputs and then having the function return `None` if the user indicated (by an empty entry for credit, for example) that they had completed their input. So then you could write something like:

```
creds = []
choices = []
courses = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh"]
for course in courses:
    res = get_credit_and_score(course+" course")
    if not res:
        break
    cred, choice = res
    creds.append(cres)
    choices.append(choice)
```

At the end of this logic you will have a list of credits in `creds` and a list of grades in `choices` and be in a position to calculate your required results more easily (I trust).

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I don't have access to Python at the moment, so this is all completely untested - though any issues should be easy to fix.

First thing (at least I would say) is that you need to break the code down into smaller chunks.

Describe what it's doing:

1. Read in 7 course credits and their corresponding grades
2. Convert grades to numbers (0 -> 4)
3. Calculate weighted average of grades

Now tackle each of these one at a time:

**Read in 7 course credits and their corresponding grades:**

You can do this with `raw_input` if you like, although i've personally always preferred using command line arguments if you're going to make a small program out of it, You get just as much functionality, and it's normally more convenient for the user (i.e. if they make a mistake, they can just change one part of the command line, rather than redoing the whole interactive process).

An easy way to do this is to use the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) package, which gives you POSIX style arguments in a nice easy way:

```python
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="This program will calculate a Semester GPA for a given set of courses.")
parser.add_argument("-c", "--credits", dest="credits", nargs="+", help="A list of credits for each course", type=int)
parser.add_argument("-g", "--grades", dest="grades", nargs="+", help="A list of grades corresponding to the credits", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

If you then ran this code in the terminal:

> ```
> $ python gpa.py -h
>
> usage: gpa.py [-h] [-c CREDITS] [-g GRADES]
>
> Change the option prefix characters
>
> optional arguments:
>   -h, --help        show this help message and exit
>   -c, --credits     A list of credits for each course
>   -g, --grades      A list of grades corresponding to the credits
> ```

And then you'd just use it like:

```bash
$ python gpa.py -c 4 4 4 -g A B C
```

Then inside the program again, you could gain access to these inputs by just accessing `args.grades` or `args.credits`, where each would be a list.

**Convert grades to numbers (0 -> 4)**

There is a pretty simple rule evident here, `A,B,C,D,F` get mapped to `4,3,2,1,0`, and then `+/-` can potentially modify the grade by `+-1/3`. On top of this, a grade is either `FAIL`, or has a letter component, and a modifier. You could make a class out of this, but it seems a little overkill in this instance:

```python
def grade_to_score(grade):
  """
  Logic here is pretty simple, and can be divided into three steps:
    1. Is the grade a fail?
    2. Does the grade have a modifier?
      y: split the grade into a letter and a modifier
      n: set the modifier to 0, leave the grade as is.
    3. Sum the result of the grade mapped to the score, and the modifier

    (4. make sure the score isn't over 4 at the end.)
  """

  # First lets just make it all lowercase and remove white space to simplify things
  grade = grade.lower().strip()

  if "f" in grade: return 0.0 # Easy first test

  modifier = None
  if len(grade) == 2:
    grade, modifier = grade[0], grade[1]

  # Look up dictionaries for grade and modifier maps to integers:
  grade_lookup = {'a':4, 'b':3, 'c':2, 'd':1}
  mod_lookup = {'+':1/3., '-':-1/3., None:0.0}

  return min(grade_lookup[grade] + mod_lookup[modifier], 4.0)
```

That will then convert any grade into a corresponding score.

**Calculate weighted average of grades**

And then finding the weighted mean of those scores using the credits as weights:

```
weighted_mean = 0.0
for credit, grade in zip(args.credits, args.grades):
  weighted_mean += credit * grade_to_score(grade)
weighted_mean /= sum(args.credits)
```

Put all of those together, and you should have a working program (though it's untested so I've likely made a small easy to fix mistakes):

```python
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="This program will calculate a Semester GPA for a given set of courses.")
parser.add_argument("-c", "--credits", dest="credits", nargs="+", help="A list of credits for each course", type=int)
parser.add_argument("-g", "--grades", dest="grades", nargs="+", help="A list of grades corresponding to the credits", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()


def grade_to_score(grade):
  """
  Logic here is pretty simple, and can be divided into three steps:
    1. Is the grade a fail?
    2. Does the grade have a modifier?
      y: split the grade into a letter and a modifier
      n: set the modifier to 0, leave the grade as is.
    3. Sum the result of the grade mapped to the score, and the modifier

    (4. make sure the score isn't over 4 at the end.)
  """

  # First lets just make it all lowercase and remove white space to simplify things
  grade = grade.lower().strip()

  if "f" in grade: return 0.0 # Easy first test

  modifier = None
  if len(grade) == 2:
    grade, modifier = grade[0], grade[1]

  # Look up dictionaries for grade and modifier maps to integers:
  grade_lookup = {'a':4, 'b':3, 'c':2, 'd':1}
  mod_lookup = {'+':1/3., '-':-1/3., None:0.0}

  return min(grade_lookup[grade] + mod_lookup[modifier], 4.0)



weighted_mean = 0.0
for credit, grade in zip(args.credits, args.grades):
  weighted_mean += credit * grade_to_score(grade)
weighted_mean /= sum(args.credits)
print weighted_mean
```

Comment: to the editors: the `language-all` language hint is for suggesting the language to *all* of the code blocks, rather than just the one you're giving the hint to. I was using `language: python`, and it's been changed to `language-all: lang-py`: `language-all` aside, the spec says that you can use either a `language-code`, or a `tag`. It says that if you use a `tag`, it uses the default language of the tag, but to be wary as they all start as `Null`, though i don't believe python is still null. So, why the edit?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is a testament to a careful attention to detail. There is so much potential for copy/paste bugs, yet I cannot see any. You have been fastidious.

Given an assignment like this, I assume that you are aware of loops, and functions. This code is begging for that. Why have you ignored those programming features?

The user input can be extracted to simple functions:

```
def getName (prefix) :
    return raw_input(prefix + " course name: ")

def getCredit (prefix) :
    while True :
        credit = raw_input(prefix + " course credit: ")
        try :
            return int(credit)
        except ValueError :
            print 'Invalid input, Should be an positive interger'

def getGrade (prefix) :
    while True :
        grade = raw_input(prefix + " course grade: ")
        if grade in ["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]:
            return grade
```

The calculation of of the points for each grad can be extracted as well:

```
def calcPoints (grade, intcred) :

    if grade in {"A+", "a+", "A", "a"}:
        return 4.0 * intcred

    if grade in {"A-", "a-"}:
        return 3.67 * intcred

    if grade in {"B+", "b+"}:
        return 3.33 * intcred

    if grade in {"B", "b"}:
        return 3.0 * intcred

    if grade in {"B-", "b-"}:
        return 2.67 * intcred

    if grade in {"C+", "c+"}:
        return 2.33 * intcred

    if grade in {"C", "c"}:
        return 2.0 * intcred

    if grade in {"C-", "c-"}:
        return 1.67 * intcred

    if grade in {"D+", "d+"}:
        return 1.33 * intcred

    if grade in {"D", "d"}:
        return 1.0 * intcred

    return 0.0
```

For the most part, the code above is a simple copy/paste of your code, with some restructuring, and variable names no longer have the qualifier.

So, with the above code, we can have:

```
prefixes = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh"]

for prefix in prefixes :
    course = getName(prefix)
    if not course :
        break

    credit = getCredit(prefix)
    grade = getGrade(prefix)

    points = calcPoints(grade, credit);
```

There, we can loop through 7 courses, and exit early if the course name is empty. We can get the credits, and grades, and points.

Extending it further, you can have:

```
sumCredits = 0.0
sumPoints = 0.0
prefixes = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh"]
courses = []

for prefix in prefixes :
    course = getName(prefix)
    if not course :
        break

    credit = getCredit(prefix)
    grade = getGrade(prefix)

    points = calcPoints(grade, credit);

    courses.append( "%-20s %8d %8s" % (course, credit, grade) )

    sumCredits += credit
    sumPoints += points

print "%-20s %8s %8s" % ("COURSE", "CREDITS", "GRADE")
print "%-20s %8s %8s" % ("------", "-------", "-----")
for line in courses:
    print line

if sumCredits > 0 :
    print "SEMESTER GPA = %.2f" % (sumPoints / sumCredits)

else :
    print "SEMESTER GPA = 0"
```

With the above you can enter up to 7 courses, and calculate the GPA.

Note, all I did was extract repetitive code to a function, use a for-loop, and store the results in an array.

Comment: `calcPoints` could be simplified with `.lower` and a dictionary. A minified version: `min(4, round({"a":4,"b":3,"c":2,"d":1}[grade[0].lower()] + {"+":0.333,"":0,"-":-0.333}[grade[1:]], 2))`.

Comment: @Veedrac - yes, The code above is an incremental suggestion. If it were me, I would probably use lower-case, and then reference things back to an associative-array/dictionary with the factors. I figured one thing at a time, though.

Comment: everythingis working fine, but how do i skip the subject? wheni press enter on the course name, it comes back to first course name and prints Semester gpa=0

Comment: everything is working fine, but how do i skip the subject? wheni press enter on the course name, it comes back to first course name and prints Semester gpa=0

Answer (score 3):

Two very minor points on top of the larger changes others suggest

You `import string` and only use this to call `string.atoi`. If you look in the docs, this is marked deprecated with

> Deprecated since version 2.0: Use the `int()` built-in function.

Your first line of actual code is 139 chars long. You should wrap lines like this. The simplest method is just:

```
print "This program will calculate a Semester GPA for a given set of courses.",
print "Enter 0 in all inputs, if you want to skip extra courses."
print
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got some good feedback here, I'm just going to two sections of your code:

```
["A+", "a+", "A", "a","A-", "a-", "B+", "b+", "B", "b", "B-", "b-", "C+", "c+", "C", "c","C-", "c-", "D+", "d+", "D", "d", "D-", "d-", "FAIL", "fail"]
```

As already noded, make that a variable, however, the upper and lower case is unnecessary. Plus, what happens if I enter "FaIl"? Your code doesn't work.

At a minimum:

```
validGrade = ["a+", "a", "a-", 
              "b+", "b", "b-", 
              "c+", "c", "c-",
              "d+", "d", "d-",
              "fail"
             ]
```

Then, you would use:

```
if(grade.lower() in validGrade):
    # Do stuff
```

Notice, your list is now half the size, which means faster searching, and the way it's formatted with each letter on it's own line, IMO, is 10x more readable.

---

My second section that seems ridiculous is your switch statement, which seems unnecessarily long.

Check this out:

```
def GPA_from_letter(grade):
    grade = grade.lower()

    if(grade == "a+"):
        return 4.0
    elif(grade == "fail"):
        return 0.0
    elif(len(grade) > 2 or len(grade) < 1):
        throw AttributeError("Bad input")

    letterValues = ["a": 4, "b": 3, "c": 2, "d": 1, 
                    "-": (-0.33), "+": (0.33)]

    try:
        # Initial grade letter
        grade = letterValues[grade[0]]

        # If we have a second character
        if(len(grade) == 2):
            # Add or subtract 0.33, depending if + or -
            grade += letterValues[grade[1]]

        return grade
    except IndexError:
        throw AttributeError("Bad Input")
```

*Disclaimer: Written freehand and untested. May contain typos / syntax errors to be fixed by the asker*